# How to create offline private registry of verdaccio

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish, verdaccio

I create private `npm registry` with `verdaccio`.

I want to able to run `npm install --registry="http://localhost:4873"` and get all dependencies from private `registry`.

I need to publish all packages from my project `node_modules` directory.

I had to run `npm publish` in each package in `node_module` directory.(I could't find any better way.)

more of them published successfully But in some case, I encountered with the error. for example in `zone.js` package:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 2 npm ERR! zone.js@0.8.29

prepublish: `tsc && gulp build` npm ERR! Exit status 2 npm ERR! npm

ERR! Failed at the zone.js@0.8.29 prepublish script. npm ERR! This is

probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging

output above. npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules

missing, did you mean to install?
```

or in `acorn` package:

```
acorn@5.7.3 build:main C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test ng\ng-prj\node_modules\acorn

rollup -c rollup/config.main.js

'rollup' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! acorn@5.7.3 build:main: `rollup -c rollup/config.main.js`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the acorn@5.7.3 build:main script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: The packages you try to publish are public packages from global npm repository ? If they are is there any specific reason to publish them in your private repo ?

Comment: I publish from local node_module. Is it different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here Verdaccio maintainer.

> I want to able to run npm install --registry="http://localhost:4873" and get all dependencies from private registry.

What do you want is to have an offline registry with all your dependencies. Publish all `node_modules` is not practical and almost impossible.

> more of them published successfully But in some case, I encountered with the error. for example in zone.js

That's the point, you would need to build each dependency, it just does not make sense. A regular project can easily have thousands of dependencies and sub dependencies. Not to mention you would lose the adventage of future dependencies updates.

So, what you need is **cache** properly all dependencies in your storage folder.

1. Run verdaccio `$> verdaccio`
2. Be sure you are online
3. Run `npm install --registry="http://localhost:4873`
4. When the finish to install, inspect your local cache, see [here how to find it](https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/cli#default-storage-location). You should be able to see all the resolved dependencies in the cache.
5. If you want a real offline experience, comment the `proxy` from the config file as follows

```
packages:
  '@*/*':
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated
    # proxy: npmjs

  '**':
    access: $all
    publish: $authenticated
    # proxy: npmjs
```

> If you comment out `proxy` Verdaccio won't ask for any update to the remotes, by default is `npmjs`, thus, no connection to external networks will be performed.

6. Restart Verdaccio
7. Repeat process as much time you need.

So, here, the advantages of this approach.

1. When yo back offline (you must comment out the proxy section again) you will allow Verdaccio to resolve wether you have new dependencies to be cached (in case you are using semver eg: `lodash: ^1.5.6`)
2. You will have a real installation experience, no fear to remove `node_modules` and clean the `npm cache` as well.
3. Storage is just a folder, so you can port it to another place (via USB or LAN)
4. Share cache with multiple projects and node package manager tools (yarn, npm or pnpn)
5. You don't have to publish each package in `node_modules`, thus see point 2).

I hope this helps you. Furthermore, there are other practices related with offline mode, but only with [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2016/11/24/offline-mirror/).

Comment: thanks @JuanPicado.
exactly, my target is the `offline npm registry`.
I wanna when  I use this command(e.g: `ng new project-name`) It's installed with all dependencies from my local registry.
is it possible?
I try to Implement your solution, but I don't successed.
I installed `verdaccio` in `windows 8` with default settings and follow your stages.
but i had problems.

Comment: is this the default **catch** path in `windows 8` ? `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`.
I changed the `./storage` path to `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`(is it true?).
then I comment `proxy:npmjs` section and ...
but it's not resolved.

Comment: `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` is not a verdaccio thing.  https://verdaccio.org/docs/en/cli#default-storage-location The folder should be named `xx/.local/share/verdaccio/storage/`

Comment: can you help me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293800/how-to-update-the-offline-registry-of-verdaccio

Comment: can you help me:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63499232/npm-err-503-service-unavailable-in-publish-package

Comment: Does anyone know if it's possible to install packages directly from storage? E.g. I want to publish my app on a computer without network or internet, I can only transfer files using usb flash?

Answer (score 0):

We used Juan Picado's advice above. Here's what we did:

1. edit verdaccio's config file at /home/verdaccio/config.yaml
2. make sure that proxying is allowed
3. set the npm registry to point to your verdaccio instance
4. create a folder (any folder) on the system and run npm install commands to download packages
5. check the /home/verdaccio/storage/ directory. The downloaded packages plus their dependencies should now be in that directory.
6. edit verdaccio's config file, commenting out the two "proxy" lines so that proxying is turned off
7. restart verdaccio

At this point running npm install commands will only point to your verdaccio instance without going out to registry.npmjs.com and the packages in /home/verdaccio/storage will be your offline-available packages.