# How to update the offline registry of verdaccio?

Tags: npm, npm-install, verdaccio

I installed the `verdaccio` in `windows 8` **os** and It's working well.

my problem started when I tried to update the `npm-cache`.

after the update version of `package.json` file, I use the `npm install --registry="http://localhost:4873` command for update `npm-cache`.

when I exec above command, it's start to install the packages, But after a while, I encountered with errors:

[image: verdaccio npm error]

or

[image: verdaccio npm error]

when I add that package (`e.g request@^2.88.0`) in `package.json=>dependencies`, It's installed but I encountered with next error package and loop ...

I clean the `catch` with `npm cache clean --force`. and remove the `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` folder physicsally and reinstall. But to no avail.

I use the `verdaccio@^4.4.0`.
`npm` version is `6.3.14`.
`node` version is `12.14.0`.

how to fix this problem?

**UPDATE:**

I did the following:

1. update `veraccio` to version `4.4.2`.
2. set registry config `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.com/`.
3. clean `cache` with this command `npm cache clean --force`.
4. update `npm` globally with `npm i -g`.
5. set registry config `npm config set registry http://localhost:4873/`.
6. and run `npm i`.

much better and resolve above errors. but I have new error:

[image: verdaccio error]

**config.yaml:**

```
storage: ./storage 
plugins: ./plugins  
web:   
    title: Verdaccio

auth:   
  htpasswd:
    file: ./htpasswd

uplinks:   
  #npmjs:
    #url: https://registry.npmjs.org/

packages:   '@*/*':
    access: $all
    publish: $all
    unpublish: $all
    #proxy: npmjs

  '**':
    access: $all
    publish: $all
    unpublish: $all
    #proxy: npmjs

server:   keepAliveTimeout: 60

middlewares:   audit:
    enabled: true

logs:
  - { type: stdout, format: pretty, level: http }
```

**package.json:**

```
{
   "name": "AngularModules",
   "version": "2.0.0",
   "scripts": {
      "ng": "ng",
      "start": "ng serve",
      "build": "node package-builder",
      "test": "ng test",
      "lint": "ng lint",
      "e2e": "ng e2e"
   },
   "private": true,
   "dependencies": {
      "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
      "@angular/animations": "^6.1.4",
      "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
      "@angular/common": "^6.1.10",
      "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.10",
      "@angular/core": "^6.1.10",
      "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.17",
      "@angular/forms": "^6.1.10",
      "@angular/http": "^6.1.10",
      "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.10",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.10",
      "@angular/router": "^6.1.10",
      "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
      "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^4.0.0",
      "@ngu/carousel": "^1.5.5",
      "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "2.1.2",
      "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "2.1.2",
      "@ngx-prism/core": "^2.0.1",
      "@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",
      "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
      "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^13.1.0",
      "@types/prismjs": "^1.16.0",
      "angular-calendar": "^0.25.2",
      "angular-material-fileupload": "0.0.11",
      "angular-tree-component": "^7.2.1",
      "buffer": "^5.4.3",
      "chart.js": "2.7.2",
      "core-js": "^2.6.11",
      "d3": "^5.15.0",
      "devextreme": "18.1.5",
      "devextreme-angular": "18.1.5",
      "dragula": "3.7.2",
      "events": "^3.1.0",
      "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
      "intl": "1.2.5",
      "jszip": "3.1.5",
      "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
      "lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
      "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
      "moment": "^2.24.0",
      "ncp": "^2.0.0",
      "ng-animate": "^0.3.4",
      "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
      "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
      "ng2-file-upload": "1.3.0",
      "ng2-jalali-date-picker": "^2.2.7",
      "ng2-pdfjs-viewer": "^0.2.29",
      "ng2-validation": "4.2.0",
      "ng6-breadcrumbs": "1.0.7",
      "ngx-export-as": "^1.4.0",
      "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^6.3.1",
      "ngx-quill": "^3.6.0",
      "primeicons": "^1.0.0",
      "primeng": "^6.1.7",
      "print-js": "^1.0.63",
      "prismjs": "^1.19.0",
      "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
      "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
      "screenfull": "3.3.2",
      "stream": "0.0.2",
      "timers": "^0.1.1",
      "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.13.1",
      "zone.js": "^0.8.29"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.7.5",
      "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "^0.7.5",
      "@angular/cli": "^6.2.9",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.10",
      "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.10",
      "@schematics/angular": "0.8.9",
      "@schematics/update": "0.8.9",
      "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.16",
      "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
      "@types/node": "^10.5.8",
      "codelyzer": "~4.4.4",
      "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
      "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
      "karma": "~2.0.4",
      "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
      "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
      "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.6",
      "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
      "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
      "ng-packagr": "^3.0.0",
      "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
      "protractor": "^5.4.2",
      "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
      "ts-node": "~7.0.1",
      "tsickle": "^0.38.0",
      "tslib": "^1.10.0",
      "tslint": "~5.11.0",
      "typescript": "^2.9.2"
   }
}
```

any opinion?

Comment: did you install it globally?

Comment: do you mean this? `npm install -g registry="http://localhost:4873"`.

Comment: npm install --global verdaccio use this command and then go to your project and then use npm install verdaccio

Comment: i mean to say first install it globally and then install it into your project !!!

Comment: tanks @SaadSohail. You mentioned an important point. I first install globally then use in locally. I did this.

Comment: I am happy it work for you !!

Comment: could you attach the verdaccio config to your example?

Comment: I attach the `config.yaml` and `package.json`. I updated the `npm-cache` then I set `npm registry` to `verdaccio`. my `XDG_DATA_HOME` value is `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are running into errors is that those packages do not exist in your local verdaccio, but on the regular npm registry.

You could solve this by either:

1. setting the regular npm registry as an uplink
2. set a scope for your registry by running `npm config set @<scope>:registry <your verdaccio>`
   now all packages that start with `@<scope>/` will be fetched from you verdaccio, but all others will be fetched from npm.